# Can this kind of code (if ... for if ... for ...) be both short and fast

Tags: python

I have some problems with the following kind of code:

```
if a == b:
    forloop:
        CODE_1
        k = t    # t will be changed in CODE_1 and CODE_2
        CODE_2
elif a == c:
    forloop:
        CODE_1
        k = t + 1
        CODE_2
```

As you can see, both the code in two for loop is very similar (they might just have some difference in several characters. The above is just an example.) Now I want to make it shorter because they are nearly the same.

I know there is a way to make it shorter:

```
forloop:
    CODE_1
    if a == b:
        k = t
    elif a == c:
        k = t + 1 
    CODE_2
```

But the point is for every loop, it will need to do the comparison. I think it should be slower than the former one. And in fact, because `a`, `b` and `c` will not be affected by the for loop, it does not need to compare them every loop. Could anybody tell me how to make it shorter without making it slower?

I am now using python.

Sorry for not providing a specific code because I am just curious about this general situation. If this can be optimized only in some specific code, it will be great if you can point it out.

And copying is not the way to solve it since they still have some difference (not just 1 maybe 25 positions).

Comment: Please provide your actual code. One of your versions is probably wrong for your purposes.

Comment: Do `a`, `b`, and `c` change during the loop?

Comment: You can wrap for-loop in a function and then call it

Comment: Have you checked if the speed difference is even noticeable? If this kind of micro-optimization matters in your program, Python may not be the right language to use.

Comment: I have modified the statement of the problem and I hope it will be more clear.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino No, they will not be changed. Only `t` will.

Answer (score 1):

If `a == c`, you could simply call `t = t + 1` before the loop, and use the same code whatever `a` is.

If `t` itself changes during the loop, you could write `k = t + dt`, where `dt` has been set to 0 or 1 depending on the value of `a`.

This should work, because, as you mentioned in your question:

> And in fact, because a, b and c will not be affected by the for loop

Finally, it might be possible to use a dict instead of elif statements.

Comment: But `t` might be changed during the loop.

Comment: `k = t + dt` is actually a good solution for that! But this could only be work in some specific code. Is there any general solution for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing another answer, you can lift comparisons and other code out of the loop.
Say that `a == c` is really expensive--perhaps they are big matrixes.  You could do something like

```
compare = a == c #store comparison
for ... :
    if compare:
        ...
    else: ...
```

You can also pull any  operations and computations that are constant out of the loop.

Comment: That is a good point. However, if we can not even tolerate the speed of a simple comparison (e.g. comparison between two int value), how to make it shorter and faster.

Comment: If you cannot tolerate the simple comparison, copy the code or use something other than Python.